# Why can't I create a Google Chrome extension from the CLI?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, google-chrome-extension

I'm a bit confused, but I can't create a `.crx` package from the CLI in Linux. In Windows 7 the script worked fine, but in Linux it seems that nothing happens. The popup window that occurs after the packaging process doesn't appear and the `.crx` is not created at all.

Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

google-chrome --pack-extension=~/Web/client/ --pack-extension-key=~/Web/client.pem
exit 0
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, (at least Ubuntu 10.04) `google-chrome` is a bash script wrapper of the `chrome` executable.

First, You should find where the `chrome` executable is. In my case: `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`

Then, replace it in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

/opt/google/chrome/chrome --no-message-box --pack-extension=/extfolder/Web/client/ --pack-extension-key=/extfolder/Web/client.pem
exit 0
```

It is really important that in the script to specify the full path. For instance, /home/me/Web/client.pem rather than ~/Web/client.pem because as it is a parameter bash does not resolve it.

A better alternative would be defining a bash variable called `$CHROME_PATH` so it can be easily changed among different *nix platforms.

Comment: well, nothing has changed :( script is still calm and doesn't output/create anything.

sp@staypositiveru:~$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --pack-extension=~/Web/client/ --pack-extension-key=~/Web/client.pem
sp@staypositiveru:~$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --pack-extension=~/Web/client/ --pack-extension-key=~/Web/client.pem
sp@staypositiveru:~$

Comment: @1999 I added the parameter '--no-message-box' (as I have done in my PC but I forgot to add). It works by no opening a new Google Chrome window (like an exclusively CLI mode). Does it works adding that parameter?

Comment: well... still the same.. seems strange. i'll try to think about it tomorrow :(

Comment: I got it, the issue is the `~`, try using instead `/home/yourhomefolder`

Comment: Using the `chrome` executable directly didn't work for me. (And it's unclear to me why the fact that `google-chrome` is a wrapper script is even relevant - presumably it passes on its arguments to `chrome`, so why does it matter that it's a wrapper?) A tentative -1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why packaging with `google-chrome` on Linux doesn't work, but can at least propose a workaround - use one of the officially-blessed packaging scripts listed at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx#scripts. There is currently one for Bash and one for Ruby.

Comment: this answer looks more like a comment to the question, maybe adding the content from the URL can improve the answer

Comment: @AvinashR I've rolled back your edit. Not including the script's source code was a deliberate choice; I recognize that some folks will view this as being a link-only answer (and therefore not allowed) in its current form, and they might even be right per the letter of the rules, but I just don't think it helps anybody for me to copy and paste the entire source of a third-party tool (which Google are responsible for hosting and maintaining) into my answer. Doing that will just guarantee that if Google need to update their script, future readers will get an obsolete version of it.

Comment: I added the content as google can remove the same and let the community manage it any other way. I understand that the script can be gone out of sync, but given the URL of the source of the script, it is implied that the script needs be revalidated by the person copy-pasting it in the future (that is why it's told not to copy-paste from SO blindly). So if that time comes when the script is changed by google, any other SO users can choose to edit your answer to keep it updated. If that makes sense, consider adding the edit.